# Mail.app opens spontaneously

Tags: macos, mail.app, bug

Mail.app opens spontaneously. Not on startup, but during my work. Even if i don't touch keyboard or mouse mail.app can open a half window.

I'm working with IDE in fullscreen mode and Mail.app splits screen spontaneously.

Is there a way to detect, who is opening Mail.app?

Comment: Which version of macOS are you using?  Can you try booting into Safe Mode (hold Shift while booting) to see if there's possibly some conflicting software?

Comment: Latest. Can't test it in safe mode as it happens rearly.

Comment: For me, it happens whenever mail looses connection with the google servers. No idea why it happens...

Answer (score 5):

I found that this worked for some users:

> Open and login to Google Calendar (https://calendar.google.com)
>
> Select the Setting gear icon (upper right-hand corner), then select
>   “Setting” from the pull-down menu
>
> Below the “Calendar Settings” header select the Calendars link
>
> To the right of the calendar name under NOTIFICATIONS, select Edit
>   notifications
>
> There are five options in the section “Choose how you would like to be
>   kept up-to-date:” - remove all of the checkmarks under the Email
>   column
>
> Click the “Save” button at the bottom of the page